# JavaScript - Get array of dates between start and end dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I got this code (off GitHub) It does exactly what I want except the months produced are a month ahead of the months in the JavaScript code. The months in this code are **02** (February) but the months produced on screen are **03** (March). What am I not seeing here? Is it the way the dates are written?

```
<script>
// Returns an array of dates between the two dates
var getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
      currentDate = startDate,
      addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
      };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate,1);
  }
  return dates;
};

// Usage
var dates = getDates(new Date(2021,02,22), new Date(2021,02,27));                                                                                                           
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  document.write(date);
  console.log(date);
});
</script>
```

Comment: In `new Date()` the month numbers run from 0 through 11, not 1 through 12.

Comment: Hi Pointy, Why does it only affect the month? Do I have to write a function to change the month only?

Comment: That's just the way JavaScript has worked for like 25 years now. I can't argue that it's a good idea, but good luck changing it :)

Comment: What's the best way to write this when I get the value from Jquery date picker isolate the month and take 1 off it. Will it be something like document.getElementByName().innerHTML = startDate.getMonth() - 1;

Answer (score 0):

As Timespider pointed out, `getDates` function is OK. You mus be careful when creating a new `Date` value, since months go from 0 to 11 in the `Date` constructor function:

```
// Usage
var fromFeb22 = new Date(2021,1,22);
var toFeb27 = new Date(2021,1,27);
var dates = getDates(fromFeb22 , toFeb27 );                                                                                                           
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  document.write(date);
  console.log(date);
});
```

**UPDATE: Using with jQuery's DatePicker**

The jQuery's DatePicker widget has a `getDate` method which returns a Date object that you can use directly in your function (no need to use `new Date()`):

```
// Usage
var fromDate = $("#fromDate").datepicker("getDate");
var toDate = $("#toDate").datepicker("getDate");
var dates = getDates(fromDate, toDate);                                                                                                           
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  document.write(date);
  console.log(date);
});
```

**Using with standard date input <input type="date"/>**

The standard date input returns the date as a string formatted like "yyyy-MM-dd", but it is easy to parse it into a Date object:

```
// Usage
var fromDate = new Date(document.querySelector("#fromDate").value);
var toDate = new Date(document.querySelector("#toDate").value);
var dates = getDates(fromDate, toDate);                                                                                                           
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  document.write(date);
  console.log(date);
});
```

Comment: Hi Roimer, when I get the date from the dates from datepicker they are already correct so when they run through the code posted they become incorrect, thats why I asked Pointy if something like this would revert it   `code` document.getElementByName().innerHTML = startDate.getMonth() - 1;    Sorry having problems with these comments & highlighting code

Comment: Are you using the jQuery DatePicker widget?(https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) it has a `getDate` method that gives you a `Date` object which is already correct, there is no need for "correcting" the month.